# How to exclude a container in azure storage lifecycle management?

Tags: azure

I want to remove containers and blobs except a specified container after 7 days in Azure Blob Storage. But now I only know the way how to apply filter in the specified prefix folders but don't know how to exclude specified container of blob. Is there any way to attrieve this?

Comment: I mean, how to create such a policy that can delete all blobs except specified container in 7 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, Lifecycle Management Policy only supports ***prefixMatch***. As explained in this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/lifecycle-management-overview#the-blob-prefix-match-string-didnt-apply-the-policy-to-the-expected-blobs) : "*The prefix match considers only positive (=) logical comparisons. Negative (!=) logical comparisons are ignored.*".

For the moment, you would have to separate your blobs into different containers and/or find appropriate **positively** matching rules to select the blobs you want the lifecycle management policy to have effect on.

Comment: If I set prefixMatch as "test", can the rule apply in containers like test-1, test-2, test-try...? or can only apply in container "test"?

Comment: Yes, it will apply to test-1, test-2, test-try... That really is a prefixMatch, so it will look for everything that starts with what you specified. See it like <myPrefix>* in a sense.

Comment: Has the prefixMatch as "Test" to apply to containers "test-1", "test-2" been verified?
Thanks